# django static files in production

Tags: python, django

I am getting a 404 error with my static files in production. The weird thing is that django-rest-framework and admin put there static files in the correct directory that I set up. I am using Digitalocean to host my site.

Directorys:

```
-django_project
    - django_project
    - templates
    - media
    - static
    - apps etc
```

settings.py:

```
SATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/django/django_project/static/',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/static/'
```

urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}

{% load staticfiles %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>My Application</title>

        <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


      </head>
```

Comment: How are you running Django in production?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your urls to this:

```
if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) 
    urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You need to include the initial url patterns.